# How to disable an android service using ifttt?

Tags: bluetooth, ifttt

I'm new to [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/). I would like to know how I can use it to disable services.
For example once I'm enabling Bluetooth I would like to disable internal BT service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable individual Android services in IFTTT. You can however remove Android as a whole by simply uninstalling IF Android app.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to disable device. I would like to disable Android service.

Comment: I rephrased my answer. You can't disable individual Android services in IFTTT.